# Changing RabbitMQ option ssl_options.depth without restart using rabbitmqctl eval

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I need to change a configuration item on a RabbitMQ instance without having any down time.

I'm aware of using `rabbitmqctl` to evaluate Erlang expressions. I know I can set first level options easily with `rabbitmqctl eval`, like this:

```sh
rabbitmqctl eval 'application:set_env(rabbit, heartbeat, 1800).'
```

However, since I've no prior knowledge of Erlang, I haven't been able to figure out how to set nested options without changing the whole block. In this case specifically changing `ssl_options.depth`.